# Conceptual approach for executing Javascript code from string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, sandbox, environment

Currently, I am having a conceptual issue with my application.

A user should be able to create a Javascript class inside my react/redux application and my application should be able to execute the written Javascript code.

For example, user A writes:

```
class PredefinedClassName {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  
  getSomething(parameterFromOutside) {
    return this.a * parameterFromOutside;
  }
}
```

This class is then saved as a string (important) in some database.

Next I want to load this class (as a string again) and do the following:

1. Create an instance of this class which is contained in the string... (How?)
2. Call "getSomething" method on the instance and pass my own parameter to the method(How?)

As this is a quite rare use case, there is only very little literature about it and almost no libraries.

Side note: On top of it, I should also check for syntax and runtime errors, but I consider this as the next step so first I would like to solve the elementary part.

Do you have any ideas about how to solve this conceptual issue?

Comment: Did you read about `eval()`?

Comment: Of course i did, but that does not answer the question.
eval() will only execute the input, BUT i need some way to add the users javascript to the DOM and then access it and use it (Create instance etc).

Comment: well you can load it with `<script />` tag. I’m not sure what part is hard, care to add code to illustrate how do you use the above class?

Comment: and how do i access e.g. the redux store from dynamically loaded javascript (<script />) ?

Comment: disclaimer: this is a really really bad idea for security. Proceed with caution.

Comment: ok and why @Luke? everything happens on client side in browser.
On client side eval will only execute post/get requests. i am just letting the user execute arbitrary JS within their own session.

Comment: Primarily due to your statement that the code is "saved as a string(important) in some database." Without knowing more about who can read/write which records in said database, this is a potentially dangerous design. `eval` on arbitrary, user-submitted code from a database is ripe for [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating an instance of the class which is stored in a string is quite easy actually, browsers basically do that in the background. All you need to do is the following:

```js
// Save your javascript class in a string variable:
const classString = `class PredefinedClassName {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  getSomething(parameterFromOutside) {
    return this.a * parameterFromOutside;
  }
}`;

// Create an instance of this class with eval() function, by appending the original class declaration before the instantiation, and do not return the newly created class inside the eval, just create it like so:
const customParameterValue = 5;
const instanceOfClass = eval(classString + `new PredefinedClassName(${customParameterValue})`)

// Now you can use 'instanceOfClass' as usual:
instanceOfClass.getSomething(10)
```

Feel free to ask for any clarification in the comments:)

Comment: ok yeah looks good and how do i establish a connection between "instanceOfClass" and my "redux-store"? can i send messages from my react/redux app via "chrome.runtime.sendMessage" and receive them in the clients script via "chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener" ?

Comment: Not sure since I don't know how exactly you implemented it, but you can treat the 'instanceOfClass' as if you had the class created locally, so if you can dispatch redux actions from the client when the class is declared in a javascript file, then you can do it with the code that I've provided

Comment: I think you have to manually assign bounty to the answer somehow, I'm new here do not sure :D